# How to configure PGeo driver with unixODBC and MDB Tools

Tags: odbc, mdb

I am trying to properly configure the PGeo driver with unixODBC and MDB Tools for my Ubuntu system in order to convert a .mdb file to a GeoPackage. The .mdb file is found here https://nosimagery.noaa.gov/images/shoreline_surveys/projects_zips/EC10a01.zip

I am following the instructions from here https://gdal.org/drivers/vector/pgeo.html

I installed the prerequisites using

```
sudo apt-get install unixodbc odbc-mdbtools
```

and updated `libmdbodbc` to `odbc-mdbtools`, as the former seems outdated.

My `odbcinst.ini` file is located in `/etc/`. I modified, so it now reads, but I've tried various combinations of the two blocks, file paths and file names.

```
[MDBTools]
Description=MDBTools Driver
Driver=libmdbodbc.so
Setup=libmdbodbc.so
FileUsage=1
UsageCount=1

[Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb)]
Description = MDB Tools ODBC drivers
Driver     = /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/odbc/libmdbodbc.so.0
Setup      =
FileUsage  = 1
CPTimeout  =
CPReuse    =
```

`libmdbodbc.so` is saved here `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/odbc/` and doesn't have a zero at the end.
I'm not sure if should replace the original block of code in there, or have both, as the instructions just say add.

When I run...

```
ogrinfo PGeo:ec10a01
```

in the location where `ec10a01.mbd` is saved I get the following error

```
ERROR 1: Unable to initialize ODBC connection to DSN for ec10a01,
...
FAILURE:
Unable to open datasource `PGeo:ec10a01' with the following drivers.
  -> ESRIC
...
  -> PGeo
```